# Should I reflag a user that's been making tag-only edits?

Tags: discussion, flags, suggested-edits, users

On the 22<sup>nd</sup> of June I noticed a certain user was *consistently* making tag-only edits (even when the post *could* have been further improved), so I added a comment which went on along the lines of,

> "Can you please stop making retag only edits when other things can be improved. Thank you."

He did stop, for a day or so, but then he continued so I raised a flag,

> [image]

And he stopped again for 3-4 days but now he's doing it *again*,

> [image]

Should I reflag this user? Or am I taking this too far?

Comment: It is the *edit reviewers* here that are enabling this user..

Comment: @MartijnPieters So should I flag them also?

Comment: @Sam: only if they have a history of robo-approving.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ok, noted. So should I reflag him? Or is it just me going OTT?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I could ping you the user in question, if you wanted...

Comment: @Sam: do point them to those comments, yes.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I will, just as soon as I figure out which ones are robo-approving...

Comment: I think you can leave it at that, else it will be OTT :-)

Comment: @MartijnPieters Quick question: would you class a user as a robo-approver if he has a reject rate of 1 in 7?

Comment: @Sam: no, because they may be skipping 20 other reviews in between.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Ah right, so theoretically a user could have a 100% approval rate (and still be a genuinely good reviewer) since he could just skip any edits that warrant a reject?

Comment: @Sam: exactly; skipping is a valid action too. You need to look at the actions in detail.

Comment: After our advise, your user stopped improving tags. See, no more edits after Jun 3 (date of this post). Success :)