# Sharing or redirecting available SO Q/A doomed to deletion to Software Recommendations

Tags: discussion, recommendation-questions

While reading [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268287/356440) on meta, I noticed this question (and answers) to which I had made a link in my bookmarks some month ago. (I think I also made an answer myself though not sure). But moreover: I do think I did take useful information from it.

However, I do subscribe to the fact it doesn't belong on SO.

This Q/A was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25115283/comparison-between-static-code-analysis-tools-for-c

I'm not focusing on that one particularly. I kind of remember that some of the resource-asking question/answers I liked has been deleted. Probably for the good reasons but:

Wouldn't it be nice if we granted the [Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/) site with all these questions already thoroughly answered (but then deleted for good SO reasons) ?

Just asking.

Comment: If you did this, I think someone (i.e. folks from Software Recommendations) would have go through those sorts of deleted questions one by one and make a call one way or the other. I'd be pretty wary of just dumping a bunch of questions on a new site like that in bulk.

Comment: those with really high scores would be prompted the first. just an idea.

Comment: It wouldn't work. A lot of those questions would also be out of date now.

Comment: The policy is that only posts 6 weeks or younger can be migrated. Anything older is *rarely* suited for migration.

Comment: Most software recommendation questions that managed to survive on Stack Overflow don't meet the specificity requirements on SR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Comparison between static code analysis tools for c](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25115283/1288) (10k only) is a good example for the main reason we don't allow open migration to other sites. That's a very broad, open-ended, low-quality question that shouldn't be migrated anywhere. It does not meet the [rather detailed posting guidelines for Software Recommendations](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/396). It's asking for a [comparison of tools](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/69/396), which is expressly off-topic on SR.

People need to look at the posting guidelines on other sites before suggesting questions be migrated. While they're there, they can search to see if their question has already been asked and answered.