# Why are software recomendations shoved off into their own group?

Tags: discussion, site-crossover, software-recs-se

I've posted questions in SR.Se on several occasions.  I've yet to get a good answer.

When I ask the question in the appropriate SE I either get shot down, or my question gets moved.

This is counter productive.  SR questions do NOT belong in a group on their own, but rather in the group of people that will use that software.

Here's my thinking:

The people who *do* things with software are the ones best able to make good recommendations.  E.g. Photography is the place to go to to find out how to manage an archive of 100,000 images.  Engineering.SE is the place to go to find similation software, and CAD software.

While I visit SR.Se, I don't do so frequently.  I suspect other people don't either for the same reason:  There are too many requests for stuff where my knowledge rivals that of a dung beetle.

This is reflected in the number of SR.Se requests that are either unanswered, have a single answer, or have no accepted answer is much higher than on the other SEs I've looked at.

As of today SR.Se had 21K questions and 11K unanswered/unaccepted questions.

---

OTOH This exchange was started because people weren't happy with it not being there.  How about if "Software Recommendation" is added as a tag, and people can set their preferences to ignore this tag.

Or, those who are interested in it can shoot down vague sloppy specs.

Comment: I like this idea actually. However, important is that the specific requirements of SR are met, i.e. SR questions must be specific enough. Most SR questions that are here on SO and closed are hopeless in that regard.

Comment: Would it be difficult to have tag specific question warnings about length, format etc? 
 *** I have a request on SR for photo software metadata management with a spec 4000 words long.  I also refer to in in photographic forums.  So far, just under a thousand views, a handful of  comments, and no answers.  But I don't know how many photographers read SR.

Comment: 100% of my two SR questions on SR.SE have zero answers, that's why I actually support your idea.

Answer (score 26):

The community which you *want* to direct these questions to (e.g. Stack Overflow)  [do not wish to support](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/268316/1079354) such questions.

> Well, we didn't just make this policy up out of nothing. We arrived at it based on evidence. Questions asking for tool and resource recommendations were observed to attract opinionated answers and spam, so we decided we don't want them here. Having them was making SO that much less useful for its intended purpose. The existence of Software Recommendations is an experiment, not an acknowledgement that the policy is stupid.

If Software Recommendations is not fulfilling its objective in being a useful resource for those looking for software recommendations, then that is a matter that needs to be taken up with *their* Meta community, not Stack Overflow's.