# Allow community to ban user for engaging in behavior destructive to the site

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting, community-user, banning

There are a few things that make it inappropriate for certain people to participate on Stack Overflow.  One is wasting experts' time with badly written or off-topic questions.

Another is expecting answers and then expecting those answers not be shared with future visitors (defacing or deleting the question and answer once received).  Right now, a moderator can ban the user for that bad behavior... and so can the majority, sort of.  By downvoting that user's question, other users can push them closer to question ban (there is evidence that this is happening).  Unfortunately, that provides an inaccurate assessment of the content itself (after all, what we're objecting to is their attempt to deprive others of that *valuable* content).

If we believe that

> One of the central tenets of this site is that we vote based on content, not on the owners of that content"

as expressed in [Stop mob-downvoting users on the main site for their actions there and their opinions on Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268171/103167), shouldn't their be an alternate outlet for the masses to express dissatisfaction with the conduct of a particular user?  Having an explicit method for doing so would:

1. Protect the validity of content voting
2. Allow a different sort of penalty than "permanent question ban" to be handed out by the community consensus.  I believe mods usually respond to bad behavior with a limited duration timeout.

Some other benefits of voting feedback on a user's behavior is that it can work independently of the rep system.  Heavily downvoted questions often lead to sympathy upvotes and actually *increase* the troublemaker's site privileges.  Voting on user behavior could be done without impacting reputation or privileges (up to the point that a short-term ban is assigned).

Or, should everyone just flag the bad behavior and wait for the flag to get through the queue and reach a moderator?

Comment: Umm, this is tagged as discussion, not feature-request.  So what do downvotes even mean?  They sure don't clearly express your opinion -- there are at least four different ones I can think of here.

Comment: Maybe related: [Is it possible to implement a “tribunal system” to deal with user suspension?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246335/is-it-possible-to-implement-a-tribunal-system-to-deal-with-user-suspension)

Comment: @hichris123: Sort of not really.  I'm pointing out that there is a defacto way for the mob to ban users without mod involvement, and asking whether it should be formalized.  But it is an addition to mod-initiated ban/timeout.  That question is trying to replace mod-initiated bans or at least reduce their authority.

Comment: @BenVoigt your title suggests an implicit feature request.  While users are strongly suggested to vote based on agreement/disagreement only on feature requests, anytime there is an implicit proposal or a hint of a suggested proposal in a discussion or support question, there are some users who do vote based on agreement/disagreement with what they think is being proposed.  As such, I am guessing they are saying "no" to a feature that allows the community to ban disruptive users.

Comment: @psubsee2003: Then downvotes should be interpreted as preference for the status quo, i.e. 9/12 voters have expressed "I believe in getting these users banned via downvoting their valid content, and don't you dare tell me to stop." ?

Comment: @BenVoigt I guess that is what they votes are saying?  However, I could make a guess that votes were based on more the title and preconceived notions of what the body says based on the title, rather than on your entire argument.

Comment: We have moderators.  Let them moderate.  Just flag the question, comment, or answer and move on.

Answer (score 11):

These are the current scenarios in which an account can have their access to the site be removed or limited:

- They are an obvious spammer, troll, or sock puppet (moderators delete account)
- They continually post content that is downvoted, closed, or deleted (access limited in stages by the question/answer ban system)
- They exhibit otherwise troubling behavior, such as vote fraud, abusiveness towards others, or other violations of site rules (moderators impose warnings and incrementally timed suspensions)

These cover pretty much all cases that we wish to deal with on Stack Overflow. The first and last groups in the above are handled by moderators, although spam and offensive flags by the community can hobble the first group.

Users posting low-quality content is the one group that is too large for elected moderators to deal with. This is where the system safeguards kick in. The current gradual warning system, followed by posting timeouts, is intended to address this without needing human intervention. It has a ways to go (particularly in dealing with those who try to circumvent it), but I believe that having the system identify, try to educate, and then manage those who don't learn is the right approach.

I believe it's better and more scalable to have the community focus on voting for good or bad quality content than to manually identify each problematic user.

Any community-driven voting on a user that leads to restrictions on access is ripe for abuse. There are certain groups of users on this site that don't like other groups of users, and I can easily see such a system being used to target each other. Certain chatrooms in particular are notorious for swooping down on individual users' posts and bombing them with downvotes or close votes. They would use such a system to remove what they feel are "undesirables" from the site, which will get real ugly real fast.

Also, the community is often not presented with all information about specific cases. For example, many reviewers were flagged by others asking for them to be banned for "robo-reviewing" because all they saw were post approvals. What they missed was all the spam and trash they identified, because that was removed from public view on the site.

Moderators can see this and other history (including previous flags and annotations on events) and consult with other moderators and SE staff members before acting. We've all signed agreements to never disclose this private information, and you've trusted us with acting on it appropriately. Average community members do not have this, and may jump to incorrect conclusions.

I think we have the right framework in place now, it's just a matter of tweaking how we identify bad content and closing the loopholes people use to work around the system.

Comment: What if there was some public voting/commenting system, on users rather than their posts, that fed into the moderator decision?  i.e. I don't think you're approving of the status quo where content gets downvoted to punish the user for behavioral problems, not content problems.  But I don't think that approach will stop unless something better is provided.

Comment: What I'm saying is, if the correct approach is the one in the last paragraph of my question... how do we get the mob to actually use that rather than question downvotes?

Comment: @BenVoigt - Flags act well as public commenting system on someone's behavior. If they're vandalizing posts, creating puppet accounts, or otherwise abusing the site, flags convey that to moderators in a private way (so that the user can't retaliate or so that false accusations aren't made public). I don't know how to stop targeted voting against a user's posts when they bring attention to them on Meta, but that's not going to stop if you can suddenly vote on the user. It's the traffic and visibility of Meta that drives the unfortunate voting we sometimes see (like if they had posted to Reddit).

Comment: I do expect that people would stop using downvote on question as a proxy for downvote user, if there was an actual way to downvote the user.  I don't think that (many) users have a burning desire to downvote good content... but they are willing to hold their nose and cast a vote they don't believe in, in order to send a "troll, go home" message.  (and same thing for sympathy upvotes, people casting a vote they don't believe in to send a "welcome, new user" message)

Comment: There needs to be a better way to take away reputation from users who just dicks about stuff and don't offer much other than their unfounded ego.