# Reviewing Deadlocked votes in the Suggested Edits Queue

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues, suggested-edits

A couple of times, I have come across Suggested Edits that seem clear cut but end up with a 2 for and 2 against scenario, then after a few minutes, the review is decided by a low rep user who, more often than not, chooses the wrong option.

Just feel that deadlocks should be handled by more experienced users; what does everyone else think?

My initial suggestion was, if it is possible, when a Suggested Edit is deadlocked that the system waits for an experienced editor (minimum 1000 rep, for example) before it offers the review to someone?

Since then the discussion has expanded...

> ##Other suggestions from the comments##
>
> > [@lankymart](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/692942/lankymart) [suggests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268712/deadlocking-of-suggested-edits?noredirect=1#comment78007_268712) (based off this [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268712/deadlocking-of-suggested-edits?noredirect=1#comment78001_268712) by [@mehow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2140173/me-how)) - *Instead of basing off reputation, what about using reviewer experience in terms of a minimum number of successful Suggested Edit reviews?*
>
> > [@mehow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2140173/me-how) [suggests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268712/deadlocking-of-suggested-edits#comment78011_268712) - *"count should just reset and the edit should sort of re-enter the queue"*
>
> > [@mistermansam](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/2930477/mistermansam) [suggests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268712/deadlocking-of-suggested-edits?noredirect=1#comment78039_268712) - *"user with a healthy Accept/Reject ratio?"*
>
> > [@MatthieuM](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/147192/matthieu-m) [suggests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268712/deadlocking-of-suggested-edits#comment78062_268712) - *"let the for/against cancel out each other and only decide once you reach 3 of either. Or, said otherwise, require a majority of +3 to take the decision so 3/0, 1/4, 5/2, 6/3..."*
>
> > [@ben-voigt](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/103167/ben-voigt) [suggests](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268712/reviewing-deadlocked-votes-in-the-suggested-edits-queue/271880?noredirect=1#comment109421_271880) - *"Maybe there should be confirmation required when hitting Accept on a review, if there's already at least one Reject vote. An extra step that says "Another reviewer said this edit was blah blah blah reason for rejection." And buttons for "Skip" and "I disagree, the edit really is good"*

*If anyone has any good suggestions please share them and I'll add them to the other suggestions box (based on comment votes).*

---

##Updates:##

**22-Sep-2014**

Must admit after receiving 45 votes (*at time of writing*) I'm surprise this hasn't received more in the way of answer input. I would have thought this would be a passionate topic for most reviewers, I know it is for me and I haven't been reviewing that long.

**23-Oct-2014**

Was hoping for a lot more input then this. Just going off the fact that [Let us bring an end to the "robo-reviewer" war: Phase 1 - 2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260194/692942) has attracted over 2K views suggests that a lot of community members are passionate about this topic. If you feel the post isn't quite right, by all means, let me know and I'll do my best to improve it.

> Would love some feedback from the veterans of the review queues, if you could take the time to leave an answer would appreciate it.

Comment: reputation is not a measure of experience on SO. You can't really measure reviewing experience..

Comment: @mehow I not sure I agree with that. A minimum amount of rep (say 1000) suggests that the user has tried out the features SO has to offer and is more likely to have an understanding of how the site operates. I'm not saying it is definitive measure just a guide.

Comment: umm... yeah **in theory** that's true but in **reality**  (*after seeing all those reports (meta's Q&A) and queries on suggested edits and reviewers*) it's not true. There are users who reviewed for example 10K and approved 9,995 etc.

Comment: @mehow I take your point +1 What about limiting experience reviews as in minimum amount of suggested edit reviews, I think that's actually what I meant. I understand your point about rep.

Comment: you must have heard of the [War (card-game)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_(card_game). When there is a draw another 3 cards are needed to be dealt. I think when there are 2-2 votes the count should just reset and the edit should sort of re-enter the queue.

Comment: @mehow That's not a bad idea. +1

Comment: Maybe deadlock resolutions by a user with a healthy Accept/Reject ratio?

Comment: @misterManSam And what would we consider a "healthy Accept/Reject ratio" to be?

Comment: @Sam - I don't have an answer for that. But certainly not those users with something like 800 approved edit reviews to 20 rejected that I see all the time...

Comment: @misterManSam You may find [these comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262431/should-i-reflag-a-user-thats-been-making-tag-only-edits#comment52575_262431) to be of interest.

Comment: @misterManSam Remember the purpose is just to identify an experienced reviewer not a competent one.

Comment: @Sam - I guess that's true about the skipping thing. The users I'm thinking of are the ones that approve incredibly minor / wrong edits consistently. But I guess they are harder to identify.

Comment: Or let's have an election for the master suggested edit queue reviewers ;) Select X amount of people who will deal with these cases.

Comment: Another suggestion: let the for/against cancel out each other and only decide once you reach 3 of either. Or, said otherwise, require a majority of +3 to take the decision so 3/0, 1/4, 5/2, 6/3...

Comment: @MatthieuM. I like your idea a lot!

Comment: @MatthieuM. Instead of having ~4 reviewers per proposed edit now, this would easily cause a larger demand for suggested edit reviewers... This is not a good idea as the number of reviews to perform for each reviewer is limited.

Comment: @Unihedron: And that's a problem on SO why? AFAICT, the queue is nearly always empty anyway.

Comment: @Unihedron: I do not see an issue in having *contentious* edits be massively audited. Actually, I even wondered if the threshold should not be linked to the number of votes cast: the more votes, the bigger the threshold, because 100 vs 103 does not mean much with an open-ended pool of voters.

Comment: Some edits are time sensitive: these suggestions all sound like they're going to massively drag out the queue. Honestly, I see where you're coming from (just yesterday, another user and I were coming across the same edits from a user who was farming by adding a tag to a bunch of posts, and they were being mass-approved even though the two of us rejected), but I'm not sure if extending the review time by this much is a good idea.

Comment: @AstroCB on other hand if not very useful edits start taking long time to get approved than farmers *may* consider making better changes. I.e. something like "66% needed to make decision, 10+ votes total and no decision - automatic decline" will probably not add too much load on reviewers, but slow down reviews to make it harder to farm.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov That's a good point: this would slow down the robos *and* discourage the rep-farmers. I'm still a little wary of it, though, but what you said is true.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Maybe you should post a [meta-tag:feature-request] for that. Your comment has more upvotes than this question does.

Comment: @Ajedi32: Well, we already have the feature-request here, what would be the point ?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Because this feature-request seems to be for a different feature than the one in your comment.

Comment: @Ajedi32 I fail to see how it is different? The feature request is for a better way to handle deadlocking situations in reviews and making sure a more experience user has the deciding vote. In that vain Matthieu's suggestion is spot on.

Comment: @Lankymart Yeah, I guess you're right. The original post (before edits) was phrased like a specific suggestion: "Is it possible that when a Suggested Edit is deadlocked that the system waits for an experienced editor (min 1000 rep for example) before it offers the review to someone?" The post as it is now focuses more on the general idea, and presents a number of different solutions including the one MatthieuM mentioned.

Comment: Deadlock would imply that the situation was permanently blocked in a circular chain of waits. This is not the right word.

Comment: @MartinSmith If we were talking in the context of programming then I'd agree with you, but in terms of voting "deadlock" is a suitable definition. I'm not sure tie-break is any better to be honest. Definition of Deadlock: *a situation, typically one involving opposing parties, in which no progress can be made.*

Comment: @lankymart. Progress can be made. It isn't blocked. Four people have already voted. The next person to come along will definitely make progress one way or another. In fact it is closer to making progress than something with only 1 vote as that awaits another two.

Comment: @MartinSmith If there are four people and two vote one way and two vote another you have a deadlocked situation that then requires a fifth person to make a deciding vote. Tie-break is another definition as is stalemate, I fail to see the difference?? It requires a fifth person to break the deadlock (to make any progress).

Comment: The difference is that every time I saw this question come up in the active questions list I thought you were reporting an actual deadlock bug. Only to open it and discover the question was not about that at all.

Comment: @MartinSmith If that was the case I would have tagged it as [meta-tag:bug] but your point is a valid one.

Comment: @vba4all Perhaps you should write an answer.

Comment: @DannyBeckett [sure](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/280679/2140173) but there isn't much else I can add at the moment I think.

Answer (score 8):

I am throwing my idea for the community judgement and let's see if this could possibly be a good resolution to the problematic ties.

you must have heard of the [War (card-game)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_(card_game)). When there is a draw another 3 cards are needed to be dealt. I think when there are 2-2 votes the count should just reset and the edit should sort of re-enter the queue.

Answer (score 2):

I like this. I'd add the point about rollback deadlocks too - quite often a suggested edit is accepted, only to be rolled back by the OP a few moments later, and re-done by various users. Quite often develops into a heated argument about whose interpretation of the question is right. I've also seen on very odd occasions the Community moderator having a rollback war with the mods.

Perhaps the right solution, as often, is a combination. I think Matthieu's majority idea is a good one; I also like the 'healthy accept/reject' ratio or number of successful reviews. I **don't** think rep should be the decider: it isn't really an indicator of reviewing experience.

How about this: if such a deadlock becomes apparent, the system should wait for a reviewer with good review history and offer them the review; if they decline it or if it takes longer than say 5 minutes (to address time-sensitivity), the system goes for the majority: 3-0 or 4-1 etc.

Comment: Rookie mistake when I said rep I meant the review experience (my bad), which caused some confusion.

Comment: What bothers me is that you don't think reputation is a good way to quantify reviews, but you think that "good review history" is a fine way to determine whether the review should have weight. **If you're going to be unbiased towards user reputation, you might as well be completely unbiased.** And after all, how are you supposed to figure out what "good review history" is anyway? Some people make wise reviews with very little experience...

Comment: I get that. I was basing that opinion of the fact that rep is a measure of community trust on the main site, whereas review history is perhaps a better indicator of how good a user's reviews are overall because it directly relates to the reviews.

Answer (score -8):

I disagree with the premise of this suggestion.

The fifth vote is not more important in case of a tie. Every other vote effects the end-result just as much.

If anything, the fifth vote is the one that is most likely correct, since that would be the one that the reviewer spent the most time on.

Comment: Not necessarily. The fifth vote could easily be a person just clicking "accept" when that's incorrect, and the person taking their time with the review and giving the right answer is beat out by that fifth vote.

Comment: @Kendra Yea that can happen too, but in general the more time spent on review, the better.

Comment: Yes- Unless you're beat out by someone who doesn't care. My point is, how many reviewers follow the advice of "take your time, you'll make a better choice"? I'm not voting one way or another on your answer, because in some cases this can be correct, but at the same time, that slow and careful reviewer can very, very easily be beaten out by the fast, "accept ALL the things!" type of reviewer.

Comment: Not sure I agree, a lot of the time the fifth answer is picked up by an inexperienced reviewer who I doubt even bothers to check the other reviewers responses.

Comment: @Lankymart: Maybe there should be confirmation required when hitting Accept on a review, if there's already at least one Reject vote.  An extra step that says "Another reviewer said this edit was *blah blah blah reason for rejection*." And buttons for "Skip" and "I disagree, the edit really is good".

Comment: @BenVoigt That's not a bad idea will add it to the list.